# Limit of a sequence with a special property

Tags: sequences-and-series

There is  sequence of real numbers,$(a_n)_{n\geq1}$, such that        $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_n\sum_{k=1}^na_k^2=1$. How does it imply that $\sum_{k=1}^na_k^2\rightarrow\infty$ and $a_n\rightarrow0$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$?

Comment: What happens if the sequence of partial sums of the squares is bounded?

Comment: oh...i get it...the partial sums are increasing and bounded, so they converge...which again implies that $a_n$ goes to $0$ and hence the condition fails. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

We can assume that not all the $a_k$ are $0$. Suppose that the sequence of partial sums $\sum_1^n a_k^2$ is bounded above, say by $B$. Then from the given condition, we can see that if $n$ is large enough then $a_n\gt \frac{1}{2B}$.  But then the sequence of partial sums of the squares cannot be bounded.

The sequence of partial sums of the squares is non-decreasing, and unbounded, so it diverges to $\infty$. It follows from $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n\left(\sum_1^n a_k^2\right)=1$ that $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$.

Comment: its easier to prove by contadiction

Comment: The above reached a contradiction to boundedness. But you are right, it could have been shortened.  Nice background picture!

Comment: heheehe..thanks